# For each relation, determine transitivity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

[image]

[image]

Why is b) not transitive? I checked (a,b)^(b,a)-->(a,a) which works and the c,c and d,d are related to eachoter so there also transitive, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Given that $(b,a)$ and $(a,b)$ are in the relation, $(b,b)$ should be too.

Comment: ohhhh  thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b$ is related to $a$ and $a$ is related to $b$ so $b$ should be related to $b$ but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing (b,b).

The relation is not  transitive because (b,a) and (a,b) should imply (b,b).

Answer (score 0):

There is no $(b,b)$ even though $(a,b), (b,a)$ are present.

Comment: You've identified why that relation is not transitive, but it would be easier for Readers to parse if you add a few words to that effect.